# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'calculator' has no attribute 'select' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, import, circular-dependency

I Am making a small project so i can learn python better, the project has 4 files (i could do this in one but well), 1 as main, 1 as the tool 1, the other as the tool 2 and the other as the tool 3.

i must import the main in the other 3 and the other 3 on the main, this creates a circular import. i cant find how to fix this. any help appreciated

Code:

main.py

```
import calculator
import texteditor
import textchecker

def start():
 print("Operations:")
 print("1) Calculator")
 print("2) Text Editor")
 print("3) Text Checker")
 choice1 = input("Select operation: ")
 if choice1 == "1":
     calculator.select()
 elif choice1 == "2":
     texteditor.texthub()
 elif choice1 == "3":
     textchecker.textchub
     
start()
```

calculator.py

```
import main


def select():
 while True:
  print("Type the number of the operation you want in 'Select a calculation: '")
  print("Calculations:")
  print("1) Add")
  print("2) Subtract")
  print("3) Multiply")
  print("4) Divide")
  print("5) Back To Hub")
  global calcinput
  calcinput = input("Select a calculation: ")


  if calcinput == "1":
   global num1
   global num2
   num1 = int(input("First Number: "))
   num2 = int(input("Second Number: "))
  elif calcinput == "2":  
   num1 = int(input("First Number: "))
   num2 = int(input("Second Number: "))  
  elif calcinput == "3":  
   num1 = int(input("First Number: "))
   num2 = int(input("Second Number: "))
  elif calcinput == "4":  
   num1 = int(input("First Number: "))
   num2 = int(input("Second Number: "))
  elif calcinput == "5":
    main.start()
  cont = input("Would you like to continue (Yes/No): ")
  if cont == "Yes":
      continue
  elif cont == "No":
       main.start()
  else:
      input("Invalid input. Try again (Yes/No): ")
    
  if calcinput == "1":
        print(num1 + num2)
  elif calcinput == "2":
        print(num1 - num2)
  elif calcinput == "3":
        print(num1 * num2)
  elif calcinput == "4":
        print(num1 / num2)

  else:
        print("Invalid Input!")
```

textchecker.py

```
import main


def textchub():
 while True:

    print("Text Checkers:")
    print("1) LowerCase")
    print("2) UpperCase")
    print("3) Alphabetical")
    print("4) Numerical")
    print("5) AlNum (Alphabetical/Numerical")
    print("6) Back to hub")
    ci = input("Choose a checker (Number): ")

    if ci == "1" and "2" and "3" and "4" and "5":
        cia = input("Paste Text: ")

    elif ci == "6":
        main.start()
    
    if ci == "1":
        if cia.islower() == False:
         print("Your text is not lowercase.")
        elif cia.islower() == True:
         print("Your text is lowercase.")

    elif ci == "2":
        if cia.isupper() == False:
            print("Your text is not uppercase")
        if cia.isupper() == True:
            print("Your text is uppercase.")

    elif ci == "3":
        if cia.isalpha() == False:
            print("Your text is not only alphabetical")
        if cia.isalpha() == True:
            print("Your text is only alphabetical.")
    
    elif ci == "4":
        if cia.isnumeric() == False:
            print("Your text is not only numeric")
        if cia.isnumeric() == True:
            print("Your text is only numeric.")

    elif ci == "5":
        if cia.isalnum() == False:
            print("Your text is not only AlphabeticalNumerical")
        if cia.isalnum() == True:
            print("Your text is only AlphabeticalNumerical.")

    tcc = input("Would you like to continue Yes/No? ")
    
    if tcc == "Yes":
     continue

    elif tcc == "No":
     main.start
```

texteditor.py

```
import main

def texthub():
 while True:
    print("Editors:")
    print("1) UpperCase Text (Every letter will be uppercase)")
    print("2) LowerCase Text (Every letter will be lowercase)")
    print("3) UpperCase Starting Letter (Every starting letter of every word will be uppercase)")
    print("4) Back To Hub")
    te = input("Select editor 1, 2, 3 or 4: ")
    if te == "1":
        t1 = str(input("Paste Text: "))
    elif te == "2":
        t1 = str(input("Paste Text: "))
    elif te == "3":
        t1 = str(input("Paste Text: "))
    elif te == "4":
        main.start()
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
    
    if te == "1":
        print()
        print("Here Is Your Text In UpperCase: " + t1.upper())
    elif te == "2":
        print()
        print("Here Is Your Text In LowerCase: " + t1.lower())
    elif te == "3":
        print()
        print("Here Is Your Text In Title Form: " + t1.title())

    if te == "1":
     tec = input("Would you like to edit another text Yes/No? ")
    if te == "2":
     tec = input("Would you like to edit another text Yes/No? ")
    if te == "3":
     tec = input("Would you like to edit another text Yes/No? ")
    if tec == "Yes":
        continue
    elif tec == "No":
        main.start()
```

error/traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Coding\Microsoft VS Code\CODES\Projects\Multi Tool\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import calculator
  File "f:\Coding\Microsoft VS Code\CODES\Projects\Multi Tool\calculator.py", line 1, in <module>
    import main
  File "f:\Coding\Microsoft VS Code\CODES\Projects\Multi Tool\main.py", line 18, in <module>
    start()
  File "f:\Coding\Microsoft VS Code\CODES\Projects\Multi Tool\main.py", line 12, in start
    calculator.select()
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'calculator' has no attribute 'select' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost right. `__name__` is your friend.

According to the [Official Python3 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__name__), there exist a couple of "Built-in relevant read-only attributes".

You will notice that if you make a small modification to `main.py` it will work fine (see below).

```py
import calculator
import texteditor
import textchecker

def start():
 print("Operations:")
 print("1) Calculator")
 print("2) Text Editor")
 print("3) Text Checker")
 choice1 = input("Select operation: ")
 if choice1 == "1":
     calculator.select()
 elif choice1 == "2":
     texteditor.texthub()
 elif choice1 == "3":
     textchecker.textchub

if __name__=='__main__':     
 # protect the "start()" with a __name__==__main__ guard
 start()
```

To keep it simple just remember: when importing modules, `__name__` is different from `___main___` so those lines won't be executed.

The only time `__name__==__main__` yields true is when you run it yourself from command-line, i.e. `>python3 main.py`.

EDIT: as mentioned in another answer, this does not fix the circular import issue. This is a valid observation in terms of architecture, but please remember that Python is a very flexible and interpreted language, and there is nothing formally preventing you to import from `main.py`. Just note the power of discerning "who is importing you" by the built-in attributes (`__name__`), and keep acquiring the best-practices in design outside the scope of this question.

Comment: This is not true, there will still be a circular import.

Comment: @RobinDillen please note my answer does not claim to prevent circular imports, (c)python can handle some cases without it being a problem. Please check that the program now runs error-free. The user requires the program to run error-free, and the error report suggested a circular import. As per Python's philosophy, there are several ways to avoid a problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are importing main from calculator.py, textchecker.py and texteditor.py. While also importing those in main. So, when it tries to resolve this:

```
in main.py:
--> load in calculator
in calculator.py
--> load in main
in main.py:
--> load in calculator
... you see what goes wrong.
```

there are 2 solutions to you problem:

1. in my opinion the best solution
   in all the other files besides main replace main.start() with return None. I think your program will continue working as you intended. And remove the imports from those files.
2. If you want to keep you program running exaclty as it does now(not really good practice)
   switch the order of the definition of imports and the function

```
def start(): ... 
# ecapsulate everything in a while here, and add an else: return None 
# every other input when choosing will break the loop and stop the program

import ...
```

then in the rest of the files:

```
from main import start
```

But I don't think this is ideal since you will nest function frames and thats memory expensive.

PS: also look add the other answer and add the `__name__ == "__main__"`

general advise: It's generally not a good idea to import from main. Try to design the calculator, ... keeping in mind you don't know how it's going to be used, just the bare bones functionality(in this case prompt some questions for calculations for example). then in main you can call those functions without them relying on the use case. Say you want a second interface to calculator, .. What are you gonna do then?

Comment: While it's true that importing from main is not part of common practices, importing after the function definitions isn't either.

Comment: @Gaston I thought I said that, but apparently i forgot :( I added it now!